# Tastypie - Multiform post with foreign fields

Tags: django, django-models, multipartform-data, tastypie

I'm trying to post a multiform to tastypie.

The Django model is:

```
class Message(models.Model):
    recipient = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, related_name='recipient')
```

The tastypie resource:

```
class MessageResource(MultipartResource, BaseResource):

    recipient = fields.ToOneField(UserResource, 'recipient',full=True)
```

Part of the form data:

```
POST /api/message/ HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:8286
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=Boundary+0xAbCdEfGbOuNdArY
Accept: application/json
Content-Length: 6462
Accept-Language: en;q=1, fr;q=0.9, de;q=0.8, ja;q=0.7, nl;q=0.6, it;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: C/1.0 (iPhone Simulator; iOS 6.1; Scale/1.00)

--Boundary+0xAbCdEfGbOuNdArY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fetched"

0
--Boundary+0xAbCdEfGbOuNdArY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="recipient[id]"

2
--Boundary+0xAbCdEfGbOuNdArY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="recipient[username]"

joe
--Boundary+0xAbCdEfGbOuNdArY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="text"

test
--Boundary+0xAbCdEfGbOuNdArY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image"; filename="photo.png"
Content-Type: image/png

<binary data>
```

since recipient is a related object, its attributes are in brackets.
tastypie does not recognize this is a related object and the POST fails.

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you please post the full POST call you're trying to make?

BTW, Take a look at 

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name

It should be: 
recipient = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, related_name='messages')

Comment: @ge7600 added full POST